# Problem on conducting a hypothesis test with sample data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, sample

I'm trying to perform a statistical tests for the sample data(n=63) which is the effect of smoking for time(measured in minute) to fall asleep.

First, I set a null hypothesis, there's no effect of smoking on sleep patterns. So alternative hypothesis will be there's an effect.

Here's the summary of data.

[image]

And here are two histograms for smokers and non-smokers.

[image]

[image]

I was going to conduct a test for comparing two sample means. And the test statistic will be "t-test" since the population variance is unknown.

From my knowledge, to conduct the test, I think the distribution of samples should be normal. However, in the histogram above, "smokers" samples are not normally distributed.

Is it still possible to conduct a test? I think i'm missing something..

[Edit]
smokers(n=47)
non-smokers(m=63)

Comment: Why do your histograms indicate there are 110 subjects rather than 63??

Comment: @whuber where do you see 110 subjects?

Comment: I counted them in the histograms: each depicts 55 times.

Comment: @whuber oh, sorry for the confusion. Actually, smokers(n=47) and non-smokers(m=63).

Comment: There are nonparametric tests for testing the equality of medians that you can choose from.

Comment: Because that last comment contradicts what is shown in the histograms, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear from the histograms that the distributions for smokers and non-smokers
are different. The former is distinctly bimodal and the latter may be consistent with normal (Shapiro-Wilk P-value 20%). However, the means and medians seem similar.

**Digitized data from histograms.**
I digitized the histograms to give 63 integer values for non-smokers and 42 for smokers

```
v.n = 14:25;  f.n = c(3,4,3,10,4,9,11,8,4,3,2,2)
non = rep(v.n, f.n); non
 [1] 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17
[21] 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[41] 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 24
[61] 24 25 25 
v.s = c(13,15:23,25,26,29); f.s = c(1,4,7,2,5,1,3,2,3,4,7,2,1)
smo = rep(v.s, f.s); smo
 [1] 13 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 19
[21] 20 20 20 21 21 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 26
[41] 26 29
```

Maybe my work is imperfect, but summaries are similar to the ones you provide:

```
summary(non)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  14.00   17.00   19.00   19.14   21.00   25.00 
summary(smo)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   13.0    16.0    20.0    20.1    23.0    29.0
```

[image]

As anticipated, a two-sample Wilcoxon test shows no difference (P-value 0.32).

**Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test.** The first thing to try might be a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to see if the two
empirical CDFs differ. This test detects no significant difference.

```
ks.test(non, smo)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  non and smo
D = 0.23016, p-value = 0.1385
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(non, smo) : cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

This result is not surprising because sample sizes are small, so the power to detect
a difference may be small, and we can't get an exact P-value because there are
many tied values among and between samples.

**Significant permutation test.** However, the interquartile ranges (IQRs) of the two samples seem remarkably different.

```
 IQR(non); IQR(smo)
 [1] 4
 [1] 7
```

A permutation test using differences in IQR's as metric, does show that the times to fall asleep are more diverse for smokers than for non-smokers.
The 105 subjects were randomly assigned to non-smoking and smoking groups 100,000
times. At each iteration $d$ = `IQR(non) - IQR(smo)` was computed.

Overall, these
differences averaged very nearly 0, compared to the observed difference of $-3.$
Among 100,00 iterations, there were 36 uniquely different values of $d.$ The P-value of the permutation test
is below 1%. So it seems that smokers require significantly more-variable lengths of time (as measured by IQR) to go to
sleep than do non-smokers.

```
set.seed(403)  # for reproducibility
all = c(non, smo)
m = 10^5;  d = numeric(m); d.obs=IQR(non)-IQR(smo)
for(i in 1:m) {
  prm = sample(all)
  d[i] = IQR(prm[1:42]) - IQR(prm[43:105])
}

mean(d <= d.obs)
[1] 0.0072
```

[image]

Comment: I found that a probability plot did a good job of comparing the datasets and a Wilcoxon rank sum test will drive the point home.