# Compare two ranges

Tags: confidence-interval

I would like to compare the ranges of two assays to determine if their is a significant difference in their dynamic ranges.  For instance, let's say we have 20 specimens. Each specimen is measured once by assay A and once by assay B. The results might be highly correlated and have the similar medians (49 vs 50) between the two assays but the range over which assay A's results are distributed are much wider than assay B's (IQR: 15 to 90 = 75 vs 44 to 57 = 13). In a slightly different scenario, the two assays might still be highly correlated but have significantly different medians (20 vs 150) and similar ranges (IQR: 10 to 30 vs 140 to 160, both = 20).

I am not exactly sure how the comparison would be made, but maybe a confidence interval for each IQR.  For instance the IQR for A in the first scenario might be 75 (CI 68 - 83).

In addition to the statistical method or calculation, I would appreciate guidance to appropriate code in R.

Thank you

Comment: If the data are close to normal, I would suggest using F tests to compare sample variances instead of comparing IQRs. (_It is possible_ to compare IQR's; I did a permutation test to do that in a recent [Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401269/problem-on-conducting-a-hypothesis-test-with-sample-data/401443#401443), but that's more trouble than doing a standard F-test.)

Comment: The F is pretty sensitive to the behavior of the tails of the variables in the ratio